# Highcharts: Overlapping colors in bar type

Tags: javascript, c#, highcharts

I'm trying to create a highchart of type bar that is overlapping the bars. Everything is working fine, but I don't like how is being displayed as show in the image:

[image]

I don't like that the white bar in the value '2010' is overlapping the blue color. It is possible to display the blue color until the white color starts to appear? I would like something like this:

[image]

As you can see, the colors are not being overlap in this image, the blue only takes it color until is value and the white start getting is own color after the blue finish.

My plotOptions are like this:

```
    plotOptions: {
        bar: {
            grouping: false,
            shadow: false,
            dataLabels: {
                enabled: true,
                color: "black",
                x: -50
            }
        },

        series: {
            label: {
                connectorAllowed: false
            },
            pointStart: 2010
        }
    }
```

and also, the data is getting trougth a controller in c#. The series is:

```
series = new List<series>()  {
     new series { name = "BarBlue", data = new int[] {400, 350, 420 }, color = "rgb(0, 0, 255)", borderColor = "#FFFFFF"},
     new series { name = "BarWhite", data = new int[] { 510, 200, 320 }, color = "rgb(255, 255, 255)", borderColor = "#000000" },
 }
```

Lastly, I tried setting the color as a rgba, but it was mixing the colors of the bars and I didn't like that, I just want the full color of the bar displayed.

To see the error clearly and in code, here I left the fiddler with the alpha problem.

http://jsfiddle.net/6chq4Lp5/

The white bar is overlapping the blue bar in the first case, and is causing a "distortion" in the color. If we remove the alpha channel, these blue bar will dissapear complitely, as seen in this second fiddler:

http://jsfiddle.net/kp37e6k0/

In the first bar, it is possible to draw the blue bar at full color unil it reaches his maximun point and then drawing the white bars? (inverting the display order of the bars will cause the opposite problem on case 2 or 3)

Thanks

Comment: Hi try to use https://www.highcharts.com/demo/column-placement

Comment: I am not sure if I understand what you try to achieve - try to make a fiddle with the problem. It is possible to set a specific color for each column - http://jsfiddle.net/t7dd7p8a/

Comment: @morganfree Here is a fiddler with alpha

http://jsfiddle.net/t7dd7p8a/26/

As you can see, the white bar in the first line is overlapping the blue bar. If we remove the alpha, then the blue bar dissapear. I don't want that to happen. Fiddler without alpha:
http://jsfiddle.net/t7dd7p8a/28/

Comment: Hi @Deep3015, I saw the link, but that would cause a visual effect as the bars are being two close together as two instead as not being overlap, which is my desire in this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no 'zIndex' option for a specific point - it can be only set per series.

You can split a main series into base and the overlapping one. Link the overlapping series to the base series and set its tooltip to have the base' name.

For example:

```
  series: [{
     name: "Blue",
      color: "rgba(0, 0, 153, 1)",
      borderColor: "#000000",
      data: [null, 350, 420]
    },
    {
      name: "White",
      color: "rgba(245,245,220, 1)",
      borderColor: "#000000",
      data: [510, 200, 320]
    }, {
      name: 'Blue - overlapping',
      color: "rgba(0, 0, 153, 1)",
      borderColor: "#000000",
      data: [400, null, null],
      linkedTo: 0,
      tooltip: {
        pointFormat: '<span style="color:{point.color}">\u25CF</span> Blue: <b>{point.y}</b><br/>'
      }
    }
  ]
```

For full control, you may want to create a white-overlapping series.

#### Live example and output

http://jsfiddle.net/ugwvefjt/

[image: overlapping]